# How to get the left navigation to follow user as they scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3YrDD/

I'm trying to get the left "SideBar" content to follow the user as they scroll down the "Main content".
Is there a way that I can do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3YrDD/8/

added position:absolute and jquery just look ;)